# Hibernate count rows with some criterias

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose I have a table Person and i want to count all those people whose "birthDate" is not null and they are a student.
Assuming i have two columns :

```
birthDate Date (can be null)
isStudent boolean (default: false)
```

How can i do this using hibernate.. ?

Comment: What have you tried? This is a basic query. Have you read the Hibernate documentation? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
crit.add( Restrictions.isNotNull("birthDate"));
crit.add( Restrictions.eq("isStudent", true));
crit.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
Integer count = (Integer)crit.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: What if he also wanted to see the count of isDropout in the same query ?

Comment: If you want two independent counts you'll have to use either a union or a sub-query and thus some aliasing in hibernate. Because you need to group on specific criteria

Answer (score 18):

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
crit.add( Restrictions.isNotNull("birthDate"));
crit.add( Restrictions.eq("isStudent", true));
List<Person> students = crit.list();
Integer count = students.size();
```

or if just want a single count value, and no list returned :

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
crit.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
crit.add( Restrictions.isNotNull("birthDate"));
crit.add( Restrictions.eq("isStudent", true));
return (Long) crit.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: You're fetching the whole list just to know its size? Why use Criteria when a basic HQL query is sufficient?

Comment: @JB Nizet because i would probably be using the list as well for other logic

Comment: I prefer criteria over concatenating strings, kinda defeats the purpose of hibernate if you write out sql as a string, imho.

Comment: The criteria is ok, but there's no reason to fetch all the results for a single count operation: think about when you have a query with 1,000+ results, it will take so much time for Hibernate to fill the list to only be interested in the number of results

Answer (score 4):

```
Number count = (Number) session.createQuery(
    "select count(p.id) from Person p"
    + " where p.birthDate is not null and p.isStudent = true").uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int result= (int)((long)session.createQuery("select count(p) from User p where p.mobileNumber = :pMobileNumber")
                 .setParameter("pMobileNumber", mobileNumber).uniqueResult());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it. It's working

```
public class IncIncidentListGridModel
{

    private String historyStatus = null;

    public String getHistoryStatus()
    {
        return historyStatus;
    }

    public void setHistoryStatus(String historyStatus)
    {
        this.historyStatus = historyStatus;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        IncIncidentListGridModel resultCount =
            (IncIncidentListGridModel) ((SQLQuery) hibersession
                .createSQLQuery("select count(ch.incident_capa_history_id) as historyStatus  from incident_capa_history ch, incident_capa ic where ic.incident_capa_id = ch.FK_incident_capa_id and ic.incident_capa_id='011'"))
                .addScalar("historyStatus", Hibernate.STRING)
                .setResultTransformer(
                    Transformers.aliasToBean(IncIncidentListGridModel.class))
                .uniqueResult();

        System.out.println("count result" + resultCount.getHistoryStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format the answer properly, not just parts of the answer.

Comment: "Use it. It's working" is not a helpful comment. Why would someone assume that an answer posted would not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
crit.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
crit.add( Restrictions.isNotNull("birthDate"));
crit.add( Restrictions.eq("isStudent", true));
return (Long) crit.uniqueResult();
```

The (Long)crit.uniqueResult() will cause NonUniqueResultException.
I check the crit.list(). It is an ArrayList having 2 items. The first item of the arraylist contains the count. The second item always contains a 0. Is it the expected result of rowCount?

Thanks